# Integrating brownian motion times exponential function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I am trying to calculate $$\int_0^tB_se^{\lambda s}ds$$ but I am unsure of how to start the computation. The motivation behind this is that I read (and am now trying to prove) that $$\lim_{\lambda\to\infty}\sup_{t\in[0,T]}| e^{-\lambda t}\int_0^te^{\lambda s}dB_s|=0 $$ So far I have used Ito's formula to simplify the expression inside the absolute values to $$\lambda e^{-\lambda t}\int_0^t e^{\lambda s}B_sds - B_t $$ and am now trying to evaluate the expression so that I can take the supremum and then the limit. Thank you for any help!

Comment: There were comments here before but now I can't see them, which is odd. Anyway a commenter suggested using Doob's inequality on the original problem, since the expression inside the absolute values is a submartingale. However I'm not sure how that helps to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are on the right way. Consider $ \ \varphi _{\lambda} (s) = 
\lambda e ^{-\lambda(t-s)}$ , $s \in [0;t]$. Then 
$||\varphi _{\lambda}||_{L_1} = 1 - e^{-\lambda t}$, so 
$||\varphi _{\lambda}||_{L_1} \to 1$ as $\lambda \to \infty$, and at the same time for any $\varepsilon \in (0;t)$

$$
\int _0 ^{t-\varepsilon} \varphi _{\lambda} (s) ds \to 0,\ \lambda \to \infty,
$$

which follows from the Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem. Therefore, one may check that for any continuous on $[0;t]$ function $f$

$$
\int _0 ^{t} \varphi _{\lambda} (s) f(s) ds \to f(t), \ \lambda \to \infty.
$$

Comment: Thanks this is really helpful! The only question I have is how do you prove that last limit? Also, just to clarify, you mean that last limit to be almost sure convergence, is that right?

Comment: The last relation is fulfilled for any continuous $f$. Particularly, for almost all trajectories of $B$, since $B$ is continuous almost surely.

Comment: To prove the last convergence, one may argue something like this: take $\varepsilon > 0$, chose then $\delta > 0$ and $\lambda _0 >0$ such that $|f(s) - f(t)|<\varepsilon$ when $|t-s|<\delta$ and $\int _{t-\delta} ^t \varphi _{\lambda} (s)ds > 1-\varepsilon$, $\lambda > \lambda _0$, and then estimate the difference between $f(t)$ and $\int _{0} ^t \varphi _{\lambda} (s) f(s)ds$